# xamarin forms - ios - listview header - showing bold border?

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Please see below image

[image]

please see below code

```
//PopUp.Xaml
```

```
            <ListView.Header>
                <Frame>
                    <Grid>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Product"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                   Text="Quantity"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" 
                   Text="Price"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" 
                   Text="Sub"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

                        <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
                         Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                         HeightRequest="1"
                         BackgroundColor="LightGray"/>


                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </ListView.Header>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="43*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="24*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding OrderModel_Id}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding User_Name}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="{Binding Product_Id, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="{Binding Quantity}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="{Binding PriceOf_Item, StringFormat='£{0:0.00}'}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="{Binding SubtotalForThis_Item, StringFormat='£{0:0.00}'}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>


</pages:PopupPage>
```

My Q being why does the popUp header of the listview...appear with a bold border below it? only on ios...not on android...I would like to remove it please. does anyone know how?

Comment: my first guess would be that it's an artifact of the Frame, which doesn't seem to serve any purpose in your layout.  I'd try removing that.  Otherwise, I'd suggest setting background colors on all of your layouts to narrow down which is causing it.

Comment: Ah yes it was the frame I thought it was styling of listview.header...thanks Jason